# Css with print-media is included in PageSpeed Insights "Unused CSS"

Tags: css, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, css-print

I'm using Google PageSpeed Insights and one problem appears under "Remove unused CSS"
I'm using a separate css for print-media:

```
<link href="/sass/print.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" type="text/css" />
```

Apparently, PageSpeed Insights suggests that it should be removed, because it's not used (ofcourse). 
[image]

If I remove the link-tag, my score increases with approx 5 points.

Why is it even loaded? 
What's best practice to have print-css on page, and still keep good score on PageSpeed Insights?

Comment: looks like a bug, try removing the `type="text/css"` and see if  it fixes it (unlikely but as it is an unneeded attribute might as well).

Comment: I've tried both with and without `type="text/css"`, but no difference at all

Comment: ignore the problem, PSI is a tool, not the be all and end all. Have you tried running the 'audits' tab in Google Chrome and seen if it shows up as a problem there? It shouldn't affect your score that dramatically and if it is I would guess the file is being generated dynamically each time as the only part of your score it affects is your total download time. Care to share your URL so I can have a proper look for you?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the "Audits" tab in Chrome, and get the same issue. And it acually do affect my score. If tag is removed, my score will increase with about 5 points.
And sure, here's the url for the public site: https://www.stromma.com/
Edit: If you run the url in PSI, you will see several other issues regarding GTM, just ignore them because they are out of my scope right now.

Comment: https://sitebulb.com/hints/page-speed/stylesheet-is-loaded-in-with-media-print/

Answer (score 1):

You could try two solutions: 
The first one is to embed print style inside your main css

`@media print { 
 /* All your print styles go here */
 #header, #footer, #nav { display: none !important; } 
}`

@media print will ensure that styles applied inside will be only applied for Print layout

Another approach could be to attach/detach your css via javascript, detecting if the user is printing something as suggested here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44918520/5778362

Comment: great workarounds so +1, but this is just fixing a problem for Page Speed Insights, both solutions your present break real world best practices, in reality this is a bug with PSI.

Comment: Including it in main css doesn't seem like a good solution. If I include print css in my main css, it will definitely be loaded, and will then be classified as "unused css". 
I want to _remove_ unused css, not add.

However, adding css on print-event seems worth trying. But if that works it would leave me with a question: what is media-attribute actually good for? Is it ever needed?